# Verifying my password on OS X via dscl

Tags: macos, passwords, osx-mountain-lion, terminal.app

If I know my password is `foobar` how can I use `dscl` to verify this on my machine? Of course the password is encrypted (`Password: ********`) in the output of `dscl . -read /Users/myuser`.

It's fine if I must use another utility to achieve this, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X doesn't store your password, so you cannot read it from some file or database.

What you can do is perform a log-in of some kind, e.g. using `su myusername`. If you don't want to open a shell, you can always close the opened shell immediately by `su myusername -c exit`.

Alternatively, if you're a sudoer, use `sudo -v` to just update your timestamp. It will ask for your password, but not run anything else. This will not work if you recently entered your password for `sudo` though. You can invalidate your sudo timestamp using `sudo -k` though, so just run that before `sudo -v` (and maybe just afterwards, to be safe).

Comment: Thanks, any way I use use a pipe for this so I don't have to type the password manually?

Comment: @agarrett You can write a script that outputs your password, and specify the path to it in the `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable. Then run `sudo -v -A`. It's a stupid idea for obvious reasons though.

Comment: @agarrett Alternatively, `echo pwd | sudo -S -v`. Not great either.

Comment: If the latter outputs nothing, then it's the wrong password?

Comment: Hi @Daniel Beck, the solution you gave me has suddenly stopped working... I get a usage error now.

Answer (score 2):

Using dscl, you can run this command to check a password on the localhost.  If it returns nothing, the password was correct.

```
dscl /Local/Default -authonly USERNAME
```

If you want to check it on another password server, substitute accordingly

```
dscl /LDAPv3/host.name -authonly USERNAME
```

Comment: For a one-liner w/password, it will be dscl /Local/Default -authonly USERNAME PASSWORD